# Shape of gradients returned by tf.gradients()

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have the following graph:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None, memory_size, max_sent_length], name = 'Input')
q_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None,max_sent_length], name = 'Question')
a_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,V+1], name = 'Answer')
# Embedding matrices
A_prior = tf.get_variable(name = 'A', shape = [V+1,d], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1))
A = tf.concat(0,[tf.zeros(shape = tf.pack([1,tf.shape(A_prior)[1]])),tf.slice(A_prior,[1,0],[-1,-1])])
B = tf.get_variable(name = 'B', shape = [V+1,d], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1))
C = tf.get_variable(name = 'C', shape = [V+1,d], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1))
W = tf.get_variable(name = 'W', shape = [V+1,d], initializer= tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1))
embeddings = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(A,input_tensor),2)
u = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(B,q_tensor),1),[-1,1,d])
test = tf.transpose(embeddings, perm = [0,2,1])
test_batch_mul = tf.squeeze(tf.batch_matmul(u,test))
cond = tf.not_equal(test_batch_mul,0.0)
tt = tf.fill(tf.shape(test_batch_mul),-1000.0)
softmax_in = tf.select(cond, test_batch_mul, tt)
p_values = tf.nn.softmax(softmax_in)
c_values = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(C,input_tensor),2)
o = tf.squeeze(tf.batch_matmul(tf.expand_dims(p_values,1),c_values))
a_pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.squeeze(u)+o,tf.transpose(W)))
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(a_pred, a_tensor, name = 'loss')
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
global_step = tf.Variable(0,name = 'global_step', trainable= False)
#optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.01,0.9)
vars_list = tf.trainable_variables()
grads = tf.gradients(cost, vars_list)
```

and then run the following session:

```
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
input_feed = {input_tensor : phrases, q_tensor : questions, a_tensor : answers}
grad_results = sess.run(grads, feed_dict = input_feed)
```

If I e.g. look at the gradient of cost with respect to the embedding matrix A, I get a gradient of shape (batch_size * memory_size * max_sent_length, d), so the first dimension of the gradient corresponds to the product of the dimensions of the input tensor. I don't understand why tensorflow returns a matrix of that shape for the gradient of A,  shouldn't you get a gradient with the shape of A?

Comment: It should be the shape of A. If you look at how Optimizer works, it just adds gradient to A, so any other shape will cause shape mismatch error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The value returned by the session is of type tf.IndexedSlicesValue. I'm not sure exactly what this type is for, I only find tf.IndexSlices in the docs. If I call the values property on that object and then get the shape property, I get an array of shape (4200,30), but the embedding matrix has shape (22,30). The dense_shape of the object, however, corresponds to the shape of the embedding matrix. How can I extract the gradient from the object returned by .values and what do all the sparse elements of the matrix mean?